# SonarQube plugin: Support for the coming Eclipse Mars. When?

Tags: sonarqube

We tried to configure SonarQube plugin in the M7 release of Eclipse Mars. 
Unfortunately the attempt failed. We got the error message "An error has occurred when creating this preference page".

Do you know when the SonarQube plugin will support Eclipse Mars?

Thank you.

Comment: FYI I know have now the same issue in Luna. Error is `Plug-in org.sonar.ide.eclipse.m2e was unable to load class org.sonar.ide.eclipse.m2e.SonarProjectConfigurator.` and seems related to an slf4j conflict: `Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;"`

Answer (score 0):

I did a test last week and the only issue I get was in the association wizard where no project was displayed. Not sure we will spend time to investigate before final release of Mars.

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube Eclipse Plugin 3.4 has always been compatible with Mars, this was just an issue on the Marketplace. This means that you could install it manually following the instructions described on ["Install SonarQube in Eclipse"](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse) to manually install the plugin.

Anyways, this is now fixed and anybody using Mars can install the plugin through the Marketplace.